# Get Value from XML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am having trouble trying to work out how to get a value from a XML file using JavaScript that looks like:

```
<Network>
    <Local>
        <Name>Name 1</Name>
        <IP>192.168.0.1</IP>
    </Local>
    <Network1>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <IP>192.168.0.2</IP>
    </Network1>
    <Network2>
        <Name>Demo</Name>
        <IP>192.168.0.3</IP>
    </Network2>
</Network>
```

The value I am trying to get is **Name** from **Network1** which is 'Test'

I have tried using the following code but can't seem to get it working..

```
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var Name1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[1]; 
        Name1 = Name1.childNodes.length ? Name1.childNodes[0].nodeValue : "" ;

    var Name2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name")[2]; 
        Name2 = Name2.childNodes.length ? Name2.childNodes[0].nodeValue : "" ;

    alert(Name1);  //should alert 'Test'
    alert(Name2);  //should alert 'Demo'
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: can you log/alert the value of `typeof xmlDoc` after `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;`

Answer (score 0):

As we can see below, your code snippet works, given you've got an actual XML node. Therefore your bug must lie somewhere else.

```js
var xmlString = "<Network><Local><Name>Name 1</Name><IP>192.168.0.1</IP></Local><Network1><Name>Test</Name><IP>192.168.0.2</IP></Network1><Network2><Name>Demo</Name><IP>192.168.0.3</IP></Network2></Network>";
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlString);
var nodes = xml.getElementsByTagName("Name");
var nameNode = nodes[1];
var nameString = nameNode.childNodes.length ? nameNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue : "" ;
alert(nameString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's likely, for example, that your `xmlDoc` is instead a string, have you checked its type?

Note that I've used jQuery here for brevity in parsing your XML string, you can just as easily use vanilla Javascript.

Comment: [responsexml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsexml) - returns a document object

Comment: @ArunPJohny It might also return null on a variety of occasions.

Comment: Hi, I was hoping not to use jQuery

Comment: @Aaron Do take the time to actually read the answer. Using jQuery isn't a necessity, it's used here to demonstrate a point.

Comment: @Nit Ok. Understand now.